# How to debugging code in gwt super dev mode

Tags: java, debugging, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am using gwt 2.6.0 to develop web application. Using super dev mode to run my application in development mode.

I could not understand how to use break point in super dev mode so that i can debug my code step by step (line by line).

Comment: Any reason you haven't upgraded to 2.7? It's much faster!

Comment: No, i am going to update it very soon

Answer (score 1):

This is JavaScript, so you use JS dev tools. And it has source maps (make sure to turn it on in your dev tool if not already), so you can actually see, set breakpoints in, and debug step by step in your Java code.

Some IDEs have integrations too, IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate can connect to Chrome or Firefox and supports source maps so you can debug right from the IDE. In Eclipse, you'd need the [SDBG](https://sdbg.github.io) plugin, and it only supports Chrome remote debugging protocol.

The one thing you'll likely miss is variable inspection (watch, etc.).

Comment: but vairable are javascript not java object..so how to debug java objects instead of javascript var

Comment: Java source code is visible, if you look from correct folder there.

Comment: Also needs SuperDevMode to be switched ON.